# unable to integrate spring security in existing application

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am not able to find out my problem in spring security integration. I have spent 2-3 days already.So, please help me.

below is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>cdl</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>startUpServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.qait.cdl.commons.startup.StartUpServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>startUpServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/startUpServlet.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>CDL_ENV</param-name>
        <param-value>staging</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.qait.cdl.commons.startup.CdlContextListner</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Session timeout -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
     WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
     WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
     </param-value>
    </context-param>


</web-app>
```

Below is my applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <import resource="classapth*:spring/SpringSecurityConfig.xml" />
<!--      <bean name="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"/> -->
</beans>
```

Below is my SpringSecurityConfig.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/displayAdminPage.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <security:form-login  login-page="/login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login.htm"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/login.htm"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login.htm" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" >
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Message resource -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>messages</value>
                <value>error</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Imports all configuration files -->
    <import resource="classpath*:spring/*.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:spring/*/*.xml" />

    <!-- Interceptor mapping -->
    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
        <!-- <property name="interceptors" ref="cdlInterceptor" /> -->
        <property name="interceptors" ref="cdlSessionInterceptor"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Tiles view resolver and configuration -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- XmlView Resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring-Xmlviews.xml" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MultipartResolver for file upload -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="rssViewer" class="com.qait.cdl.rssfeed.view.CustomRssViewer" />

    <!-- Default view resolver mapping <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value> </property> <property 
        name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value> </property> <property name="order" value="1" 
        /> </bean> -->
</beans>
```

I have following queries.

1. Is it necessary to give "filter" tag in web.xml, if yes than why?
2. In my application, I have two application context(one for spring security and other for dispatcher-servlet), is it possible for springSecurityConfig.xml to access bean definition which is defined in dispatcher-servlet.xml?
3. what is the flow of spring-security configuration.Upto my knowledge, i have understood that **intercept-url** tag intercept the request and check appropriate role using expression language.I am not able to understand how it looks appropriate role in DB via authentication-manager i've provided.

below is my userService bean definition in service.xml

```
    <bean name="userService" class="com.qait.cdl.services.impl.UserServiceImpl">
            <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
        </bean>
```

below is userService interface

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService{
}
```

this UserDetailsService is from springframework

below is UserServiceimpl class

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        if(username != null &&  !"".equals(username)){
            User user = userDao.get(username);
            if(user != null){
                UserGroupAuthority groupAuthority = userDao.getUserAuthority(user);
                if(groupAuthority != null){
                    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = getGrantedAuthorities(groupAuthority.getAuthority());
                    userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), 
                            true, true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);
                }
            }
        }
        return userDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String authority) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new LinkedList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public UserGroupAuthority getUserAuthority(User user) {
        return userDao.getUserAuthority(user);
    }
}
```

Simply the problem is , it is not validating the given intercept-url. Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Why your `springSecurityFilterChain` is deactivated in `web.xml`?

Comment: is it necessary to give "springSecurityFilterChain", because I think <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> intercept all incoming request. But I don't want that. So, i did comment that code

Answer (score 0):

Activate `springSecurityFilterChain` in your `web.xml`. It's an entry point of Spring Security. If `springSecurityFilterChain` is deactivated then Spring Security will never work.

Comment: but why there is tag <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> everywhere in Internet.what is the significance of this tag

Comment: after activate springSecurityFilterChain, it is working and it is intercepting url also, but problem is when it call hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') method.

and when i update my springsecurityconfig file to below file
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/displayAdminPage.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
 </security:http>
It is showing the default jsp page of spring for username and password.I don't want that, this is not good way i think because user already enter it's username and password, why this is asking again

Comment: /* url-pattern means that this filter will be called during each request. But it does not means that each response will be actually prepared by this filter itself. The filter will actually does a lot of work (for example check if logged user has permissions to open actual URL). Actual request will be prepared by corresponding servlet / controller.

Comment: I think it should be like that, when user login into my application every time, spring should call hasRole() method on intercept-url and check role from db i've provided and extract role on the basis of username, if this returns "ROLE_ADMIN" than user should be allow ,otherwise access denied page should be display, which i will provide in config file

Comment: If it does not works like this for you then you have some config issue. Enable debug logging for org.springframework.security package and look into your logs (log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG in a case of log4j).